# Is there any way to remove the b'' from decoded base64 output?

Tags: python, discord, base64

When i run

```
import base64

a = "aHR0cHM6Ly9kaXNjb3JkLmNvbS9hcGkvd2ViaG9va3MvMTA2MTQ2NzIxNDI2MTI2MDMwOC9wNklOLWgzVkRGSEo1UVIyNDVSXy1NUFlWZ2xfU2tRZ3RUemVPMUN2SGlUZlBSMEExSjhOQUdHVmt0NU1sZzhrYXVkRg=="
hook = base64.b64decode(a)

print(hook)
```

It returns:

```
b'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1061467214261260308/p6IN-h3VDFHJ5QR245R_-MPYVgl_SkQgtTzeO1CvHiTfPR0A1J8NAGGVkt5Mlg8kaudF'
```

But i want it to only return `https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1061467214261260308/p6IN-h3VDFHJ5QR245R_-MPYVgl_SkQgtTzeO1CvHiTfPR0A1J8NAGGVkt5Mlg8kaudF` not the b''. Is there anyway to fix the problem? I know it says it because the type is byte.

Comment: `b'` is only used when printing the *representation*, and the bytes are still `https://discord.com/...g8kaudF`. Are you looking perhaps to *convert* those bytes to a string of characters?

Comment: I just want https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1061467214261260308/p6IN-h3VDFHJ5QR245R_-MPYVgl_SkQgtTzeO1CvHiTfPR0A1J8NAGGVkt5Mlg8kaudF to not be readable, so i thought i would convert it into a base64 then decode when i need it.

Comment: `hook.decode("ascii")`

Comment: @DeVYuvi Encoding it doesn't make it *un*readable; it's instantly recognizable as base64, and if it contains info that must be kept secret (not sure if that applies to the discord webhook or token), then it'll be quite easy to find.

Comment: @DeVYuvi, what are you trying to accomplish? what's the end goal?

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that sends a message to the webhook without the person running it knowing there is a webhook, however not using for any malicious purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a `bytes` value that should be decoded to a `str` value:

```
>>> print(hook.decode())
https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1061467214261260308/p6IN-h3VDFHJ5QR245R_-MPYVgl_SkQgtTzeO1CvHiTfPR0A1J8NAGGVkt5Mlg8kaudF
```

Base64 is usually used to encode arbitrary binary data as ASCII text, which is why `b64decode` returns a `bytes` value. In this case, though, the "binary" data is itself just ASCII-encoded (or possibly UTF-8-encoded) text.